# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I got this error after running my client in java.

run:

```
Oct 01, 2017 8:08:07 AM from_sever.From_sever main
SEVERE: null
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at from_sever.From_sever.main(From_sever.java:26)
```

Comment: Some other program is already using the port. Stop the other program, or use a different port.

Comment: You got this error running your *server.* Read the stack trace. You haven't run your client at all yet, or at least if you have you should not have.

Answer (score 1):

Some other program already use that port.

You can check port usages by `netstat -a`. Look for your port number.

Answer (score 1):

Either change the port of your current program or just find out the already running application and kill it. Run below command in windows:-

```
netstat -ano | find <port_no_already_in_use>

taskkill /F /PID <process_id_running_on_port>
```